# dpkg -i running in background after install

Tags: dpkg, post-install

My own dpkg not installing correctly.
I run:

```
:~# dpkg -i foo-2.1-2.deb
```

when my package is done installing.

```
:~# ps aux | grep foo | grep -v grep

root      1718  2.2  1.4  10080  7308 ttyS0    S    11:59   0:03 dpkg -i foo-2.1-2.deb
root      1731  0.0  0.0   1720   496 ttyS0    S    11:59   0:00 /bin/sh /var/lib/dpkg/info/foo-2.1-2.postinst configure 2.1-2
```

I think my postinst script is not terminating correctly,

I'm missing something but don't know what.

Comment: You *really* don't want to call `apt-get` from within a postinst script. You should set a dependency in your package if you want to make something else be installed, but you probably want to recommend not depend and possibly on just a general webserver, not a specific one.

Comment: @Flexo this is a very special case where it is imperative that lighttpd is installed before anything else happens.

Comment: That's exactly what Pre-Depends is for then. You *can't* call `apt-get` from a postinst.

Comment: Ok, got it no apt-get in the postinst. Will that force lighttpd to install automatically?

Comment: Yes, it will force it to be installed before the installation of your package. I'm not sure you need anything stronger than Depends though still.

Comment: I still need to make sure that '/bin/sh /var/lib/dpkg/info/foo-2.1-2.postinst configure 2.1-2'. is not running after the installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out. One of my scripts called by postinst called /bin/bash which started a new shell that caused dpkg to run in the background and never finish.